# ASP.NET MVC. Reading & Writing Cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

Is there any difference between the Cookies collection in HttpRequestBase and HttpRequest?

Is there any difference between the Cookies collection in HttpResponseBase and HttpResponse?

If a cookie is added to the HttpResponseBase, can it be retrieved by using the HttpRequst or HttpResponse?

Thanks,

Comment: Cookies are cookies... if you add one in ASP.NET, you could retrieve it from a PHP script running on the same site, if you wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Is there any difference between the Cookies collection in HttpRequestBase and HttpRequest?**

No

**Is there any difference between the Cookies collection in HttpResponseBase and HttpResponse?**

No

**If a cookie is added to the HttpResponseBase, can it be retrieved by using the HttpRequst or HttpResponse?**

Yes (if you add it to a response, it will be available in the **next** request)

ASP and MVC cookies are identical.

Comment: Right, but we're not talking about all exceptions and contingencies, but standard expected behavior.